# Init process consuming more than 200 percent cpu

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, virtual-machine, cpu-usage

The `init` process is consuming more than 200 percent of the CPU time on my vServer, which is running Debian 7. Also, my SSH connection becomes very unresponsive after a while.

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  232  0.0   8404   792 ?        Ss   Sep14  40:08 init [2]
```

First of all: How is 232% even possible? Does the utilization of the different cores add up?

Is this normal behavior or do I have to worry about it? Can I do something about it?

Comment: The CPU usage percentage is calculated with reference to one core. If a program uses several threads, it can show a CPU usage higher than 100% (the limit would be the 100 times the number of cores).

Comment: Init should not consume this amount of CPU, can you paste the output of `sar -u ALL` and `vmstat 5 5`. Is this condition happening frequently ?.

Comment: Fortunately the issue went away without me doing anything. CPU usage of `init` is now at 0.7%.